# perl 6 variable same name different sigils inconsistent behavior

Tags: variables, raku, sigils

There seems to be some inconsistent behavior when variables of the same letter-name but different sigils are used:

```
> my $a="foo";
foo
> my @a=1,2
[1 2]
> say $a
foo               # this is what I have expected
> my $b = 1,2,3
(1 2 3)
> my @b = (0, $b.Slip)
[0 1]             # I expect to get [0 1 2 3]; (0, |$b) not work either
> say $b
1                 # I expect $b to be unchanged, (1,2,3), but it is now 1;
> say @a
[1 2]
> say @b
[0 1]
>
```

I am not sure why `@a` does not affect `$a`, whereas `@b` affects `$b`. Can someone please elucidate?

Thanks !!!

lisprog

Answer (score 6):

In Rakudo Perl 6 there is actually no relationship at all between `$b` and `@b`.

`$b` didn't change. It simply didn't get assigned what you thought it had been assigned. Looking at the documentation on [Operator Precedence](https://docs.perl6.org/language/operators#Operator_Precedence), you'll see that `=` (assignment) has a tighter precedence than the comma `,`.

Also, you are using the REPL, which automatically prints out the return value of each statement. That return value may or may not be the same as the value assigned to a variable.

`my $b = 1,2,3` actually is the same as
`(my $b = 1),2,3` because `=` has tighter precedence than `,`, meaning that effectively all but the first value is ignored

```
> (my $b = 1),2,3
(1 2 3)
> $b
1
```

If you want to assign a list to `$b`, then put parentheses around the list:

```
> my $b = (1,2,3)
(1 2 3)
> $b
(1 2 3)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Christopher !!! I got it now, and the Slip works too ! Thanks !

Comment: One might argue that `my $b = 1,2,3` should warn about dropping values `2` and `3` on the floor.

Comment: @ElizabethMattijsen Would that warning be something like `Useless use of constant in sink context. Did you mean to assign a list to Scalar?`?